# Доступ к событиям чужого калентаря

Tags: java, android, google-calendar

Необходимо получить список событий чужого Google-календаря.
Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor evCur = cr.query(
    CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{
        CalendarContract.Events._ID,
        CalendarContract.Events.STATUS
    },
    "(" +CalendarContract.Events.ACCOUNT_NAME+ "=?)",
    new String[]{"accountname@gmail.com"},
    null );
int cnt = evCur.getCount();
```

но количество событий равно 0. Если я правильно понял, таким образом можно запросить события только календаря, связанного с аккаунтом телефона, а нужно читать любой календарь с открытым доступом.

Comment: Думаю, вам куда-то сюда надо: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android